# Customtkinter entry boxes selected text color

Tags: tkinter-entry, customtkinter

I'm encountering an issue with the entry widget in customtkinter. I want to modify the color of the selected text within an entry box. It defaults to gray, and I'm struggling to find a way to change it.

I can change fg_color, text_color, border_color and something about placeholder text but nothing about the selected text.